# JOIN three MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I got three tables :

[image: Three tables]

```
== liste_caracteristiques
|------
|------
|//**idCarac**//|int(11)|Non|
|//**refproduit**//|int(11)|Non|
|valeur|varchar(255)|Oui|NULL
|0|4942|Windows
|0|8149|Android
|1|9980|300
|1|10300|1100
|1|10316|149.5
|2|4942|7
|2|8149|12
|2|9980|15cm
|2|10300|4cm
|2|10316|8.3cm
```

and

```
== caracteristiques
|------
|------
|//**idCarac**//|int(11)|Non|
|libelleCarac|varchar(255)|Oui|NULL
|0|Système d'exploitation
|1|Poids
|2|Screen size
|3|ATEX
|4|Zone 0
|5|Zone 1
|6|Zone 2
```

and

```
== types_carac
|------
|------
|//**idTypeProd**//|int(11)|Non|
|//**idCarac**//|int(11)|Non|
|1|1
|1|2
|1|3
|2|0
|2|2
|2|3
```

I need to get all value of "valeur" when libelleCarac is "Screen size" and when idTypeProd = 2

So I tried to use :

```
SELECT * 
FROM types_carac as T, caracteristiques as C, liste_caracteristiques as L 
WHERE T.idCarac = C.idCarac 
AND C.idCarac = L.idCarac 
AND idTypeProd = 2 
AND libelleCarac = "Screen size"
```

In my result some values are not linked with idTypeProd = 2

I have :

```
|idTypeProd|idCarac|idCarac|libelleCarac|idCarac|refproduit|valeur
|2|2|2|Screen size|2|4942|7
|2|2|2|Screen size|2|8149|12
|2|2|2|Screen size|2|9980|15cm
|2|2|2|Screen size|2|10300|4cm
|2|2|2|Screen size|2|10316|8.3cm
```

And I need

```
|idTypeProd|idCarac|idCarac|libelleCarac|idCarac|refproduit|valeur
|2|2|2|Screen size|2|4942|7
|2|2|2|Screen size|2|8149|12
```

In fact I just need the Screen Size value of idType = 2, my query looks good to me but results aren't

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: Your Where clause has idTypeProd = 2, which means you are only going to see results for records with idTypeProd = 2, I find it hard to believe that the first two records you are showing are false or wrong.

Comment: @jarlh I did it too whitout any difference, i'm trying to export my data and table in formatted text

Comment: @RyanWilson Sorry for bad eng, the first two results are correct :) I don't understand why others results is here because they are not idTypeProd = 2 but idTypeProd = 1

Comment: all data in your question has idTypeProd = 2 @Sydowh

Comment: how do you expect to distinguish your data between the current output and desired output, they are all the same apart from the final two columns

Comment: @Sydowh answered queries are correct, your data is wrong

Comment: Ok in fact we are all right :) I just need to make another JOIN with another table to got the product with idTypeProd = 2, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if this works. it uses the modern joining syntax which is easier to read and debug if there are errors. this query joins your three tables together and then returns your `valeur` value where `idTypeProd` is 2 and `libelleCarac` is screen size.

```
SELECT  valeur
FROM    liste_caracteristiques lc
JOIN    caracteristiques c on c.idCarac = lc.idCarac
JOIN    types_carac tc on tc.idCarac = c.idCarac
WHERE   tc.idTypeProd = 2
AND     libelleCarac = "Screen size"
```

Comment: Same result as my query

Comment: @Sydowh if this is wrong what are your suspected values then? This does what you are describing

Comment: you mentioned that you want the data where where idTypeProd is 2 and libelleCarac is screen size, if this query is wrong you have incorrect data in your database

Comment: When I select only idTypeProd = 2 and 'Screen Size' I got a good results but when I add the liste_caracteristiques table I got results which is not linked to idTypeProd = 2, results show they are all idTypeprod = 2 but I'm pretty sure they are not, take a look at my data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, using `JOIN` as explained above, in the comment section:

```
SELECT
    TC.idTypeProd
    ,LC.idCarac
    ,C.libelleCarac
    ,LC.refproduit
    ,LC.valeur
FROM liste_caracteristiques LC
INNER JOIN types_carac TC
    ON LC.idCarac = TC.idCarac
    AND idTypeProd = 2
INNER JOIN caracteristiques C
    ON TC.idCarac = C.idCarac
    AND libelleCarac = 'Screen size'
```

Comment: Same result as my query, I tried with JOIN too, maybe it's a structural problem

Comment: You should really put some sample data then to see what's wrong